eBay ApiClient C# not working for production
I am working with eBay ApiClient library for C# and I have a problem when I want to use it on production environment.
I have a problem in the following code. When I use it for sandbox environment, then everything works ok, but when I put use it for production environment, then I get message from eBay saying:
There was an error passing information between the third party you just came from and eBay.
Error code: : 2024-05-27 13:32:11 : signin.ebay.com


This error may have occurred for one of the following reasons:

The third party that has sent you here has provided invalid information to eBay.
eBay has encountered an error processing your request. Please close this window and return to the third party application.

OAuth2Api oAuth2Api = new OAuth2Api();
CredentialUtil.Load("config.yaml");
OAuthEnvironment environment = OAuthEnvironment.PRODUCTION; 
List<string> scopes = new List<string>()
{
        "https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.fulfillment.readonly",
        "https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope",
        "https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.fulfillment"
};
string state = "current-page";
string authorizationUrl = oAuth2Api.GenerateUserAuthorizationUrl(environment, scopes, state);
Console.WriteLine("Please navigate to this URL to authorize:\n" + authorizationUrl);


Check the credential settings for your production environment. If this code works for your other environments, then it's probably not the code. If all that's different is the stuff that's dependent on the environment, then this is the most probable source of error.
